# Counterexample: If $f_n \to f$ uniformly but the $f_n$'s are not continuous, then $f$ is not neccesarily continuous

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $G$ be a region in $\Bbb C$ and $D = \{ z \in C : |z|<1\}$. I need to prove that if a sequence $\{f_n:G\to D\}$ of injective functions converge uniformly to a non constant function $f:G \to D$, then $f$ is not necessarily continuous nor analytic. I tried to construct a counterexample. I'd like to know if it's correct or if there's a simpler example:

Clearly, the $f_n$'s must be discontinuous and not analytic.

Let $G=\{z \in \Bbb C: 0<|z|<e^{1/2} \text{ and } 0 \leq \arg z<1/2 \}$. Then, for every $z \in G$:
$$|\log z|^2=(\log|z|)^2 + (\arg z)^2 < (\log e^{1/2})^2 + \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}.$$
$$\implies |\log z| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<1.  $$
So, $\log z \in D$ for all $z \in G$.
Define $f(z)=\log z$ and $f_n(z)=\log z + \frac{1}{n+3}$, for every $z \in G$.

For $n \geq 1$ and $z \in G$,
$$|f_n(z)| \leq |\log z|+ \frac{1}{n+3}  \leq |\log z|+ \frac{1}{4} < \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{1}{4}<1,$$
so $f_n:G\to D$, the $f_n$'s are injective and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a non-constant injective function which is not continuous. [Take $G=D, f(z)= z /2$ for $z \neq 0$ and $f(0)=\frac 3  4$ for example]. Take $f_n=\frac  1 {n+4} +f$.

Comment: That's what I tried to do. Is my example incorrect? Is there an easier example?

Comment: @Twink I am trying to say that you made the example too complicated. No need to bring in logarithms. I have given a specific example now.

Comment: But in your example, $f_1(0)=1+3/4=7/4 \notin D$. Do we have to take $f_n=\frac{1}{n+4}+f$?

Comment: @Twink Answer corrected.

Comment: This example also works to prove that the uniform limit of a sequence of not analytic functions is not necessarily analytic, right? (since discontinuous $\implies$ not analytic.)

Comment: @Twink Yes,that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest class of examples: let $f$ be your favourite injective function that does not have whatever property you're interested in, and take all $f_n = f$.